# Next/React - Loop (add 1 row per 125 data length

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The goal of the below code is to loop the size of the textarea depending on the length of the data extracted.

```
{
  logData.description.length < 125 ? (
    <>
      <FormControl
        id='descriptionFormID'
        ref={textAreaRef}
        value={logData.description}
        as='textarea'
        rows={1}
        placeholder='Comment'
        className='mr-sm-2 bg-white'
        disabled
      />
    </>
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
}
{
  logData.description.length > 125 && logData.description.length < 250 ? (
    <>
      <FormControl
        id='descriptionFormID'
        ref={textAreaRef}
        value={logData.description}
        as='textarea'
        rows={2}
        placeholder='Comment'
        className='mr-sm-2 bg-white'
        disabled
      />
    </>
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
}
```

I'm adding 1 row per 125 length.

Example:

- 1 row = 125 characters
- 2 row = 250 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Math.ceil(logData.description.length/125) to get an integer that increments by 1 for every 125 length your description data has, then just plug that number into your rows.

```
<>
  <FormControl 
    id="descriptionFormID"
    ref={textAreaRef}
    value={logData.description}
    as="textarea"
    rows={Math.ceil(logData.description.length/125)} 
    placeholder="Comment" 
    className="mr-sm-2 bg-white"
    disabled/>
</>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You answers my question. Thank you.